# Problems migrating a working 1-Wire library in C on Debian Linux from wiringOP to libgpiod

Tags: debian, timing, orange-pi, libgpiod

I managed 1-Wire access to DS18B20 temperature sensors in pure C from userland on a Orange Pi Zero 2, operated by Debian Bullseye.

I learned wiringOP is no more maintained and would like to switch to libgpiod. I managed to address the GPIO lines using libgpiod as expected. Then I replaced in my 1-Wire test program all GPIO calls to the wiringOP lib by the respective calls to the libgpiod like follows:

```
pinMode(pin, OUTPUT); -> gpiod_line_request_output(gpioline, "gpio");
digitalWrite(pin, LOW); -> gpiod_line_set_value(gpioline, 0);
pinMode(pin, INPUT); -> gpiod_line_request_input(gpioline, "gpio");
bit = digitalRead(pin); -> bit = gpiod_line_get_value(gpioline);
```

I am aware that the pin/line number scheme of wiringOP is different from libgpiod. In my case the repective wPi pin number is 16 while the GPIO line number is 74. As I said, I verified that mere GPIO access is working either way.

Now 1-Wire does not work with libgpiod while it does work perfectly with wiringOP. I had some troubles to get the timing straight until I ported delayMicroseconds() from wiringOP into my user land program. This works now and is not different from the same program using libgpiod.

What am I missing?

Do calls to libgpiod have a huge overhead, I mean more than a mircosecond until lines become switched - this would spoil any use with 1-Wire, actually any bit-banging would be difficult.

Are there any maintained alternatives to wiringOP?

PS: WiringOP is the fork of WiringPi adapted to the Orange Pi series of SBC's

PPS: In the meantime I checked my very 1-Wire test program on a Raspberry Pi 4B operated by FreeBSD 13.2. Here I simply replaced the calls to the wiringOP library by the respective calls to FreeBSD's GPIO library. It worked out of the box. This lets me conclude that something is seriously flawed with Linux's libgpiod.

Answer (score 0):

Any library that accesses hardware via the kernel will be slower than directly accessing the hardware via memory mapped registers, which is what libraries like `wiringOP` and `wiringPi` do.

That is also why they are hardware specific, whereas `libgpiod` is generic.

For `libgpiod` the hardware is accessed via kernel ioctl calls, which at the very least involve a context switch and are going be to orders of magnitude slower than directly writing to a hardware register.

e.g. on a Pi Zero setting a line with libgpiod takes around 4us.
On a Pi4, which you used for your FreeBSD testing, it is less than 1us.
Have you tried your `libgpiod` code on a Pi4?

That doesn't make it useless for bitbanging, I've used it for bitbanging I2C and SPI on the Pi, but it does limit the rate for which it is viable.

If you need to drive lines faster than that then `libgpiod` is not the tool for you.  That doesn't mean `libgpiod` is flawed, though, it means it has to operate under constraints that make it inappropriate for your application.

Would the [1-wire subsystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/w1/index.html) be a better fit?

Both `libgpiod` and the kernel are open source, so if you feel you can improve them then you are welcome to contribute.  Or you could always take on supporting `wiringOP`, if you can't find an alternative.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Indeed 4 µs is well in the range of some timings of the ow protocol. Actually I am mostly at home on FreeBSD and I only took the adventure to Linux because of the shortage of the Raspberries, which are quite well supported by FreeBSD while it does not even start the Orange Pi Zero 2.

Comment: While I wrote already kernel modules for FreeBSD, I won't have time to do the same for Linux. So I will stay with Wiring(OP|Pi) on Linux. It is not as nice as using a generic library, but it got the advantage that it works.

Comment: Not sure why `wiringOP` not being maintained an issue for you.  If it is working for you it only becomes an issue if some bug is discovered, or new hardware is released that breaks the existing code - like the Pi4 did for the Raspberries.

Comment: It is not exactly an issue. It is only my preference to stay with generic libraries, as far as possible. I will check libgpiod on the RPi 4 as you suggested, and report the result.

Comment: So I put the current version of Raspberry Pi OS (64bit based on Debian Bullseye) onto a SD card and started the RPi 4B from it. Then I installed clang, gpiod and libgpiod-dev and WiringPi. After restart, I experienced the same behaviour as with the OPiZ2. The libgpiod-version of the 1-wire test program does not work while the wiringPi-version does. I restarted the RPi 4B with FreeBSD 13.2 and verified, that the test program linked against FreeBSD's native GPIO library does work as well. On Linux, I will stay with Wiring(OP|Pi).

Comment: Interesting.  Any chance you can put a scope on the line to see what the resulting waveforms look like?  That would help identify if the problem is timing or something more fundamental.

Comment: Oh, and 64bit seems to be slower than 32bit in my Pi4 benchmarking -  around 2us compared to less than 1us for 32bit (both Raspberry Pi OS), which is what I was referencing in my answer.

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't own a scope.

Comment: I had a closer look at the sources of libgpiod. I found 3 functions for getting/setting the debounce period (some sort of time constant) of the kernel's debounce facility. So, I called `gpiod_line_info_is_debounced(gpioline);`only to learn that this one (and the other 2 functions) are not implemented yet by Bullseye. Anyway, may it be that a debounce facility is implemented and active in the Bullseye's kernel and that it defaults to an unfortunate time constant? That would explain everything. In FreeBSD we may read and write kernel parameters using sysctl.

Comment: Is there sort of a sysctl or alike in Linux for checking/setting debouncing variables in the kernel?

Comment: Setting debounce from user space requires `uAPI v2`, added in kernel 5.10, and `libgpiod v2` which only released recently and hasn't made its way to distros yet.  At present you need to build it yourself.  (one of the reasons for v2 is that it wasn't reasonable to add debounce to uAPI v1).  Debounce only applies to edge detection - it does not effect normal gets and sets, and by default it is disabled in the kernel.  Reading the line info is the way to check, either with `libgpiod` calls or the `gpioinfo` tool - but it definitely isn't the problem here.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for all your insights. Unfortunately I don't have sufficient reputation for voting you up.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help - if I had a 1-wire device I would try it myself.  But the feeling I get is that if you want maximum speed from your hardware under Linux you are expected to go in-kernel with the appropriate subsystem or driver rather than bitbashing it from userspace.  In this case I would be taking a look at the 1-wire subsystem to see it that can do the job for you.